# Advent of Code 2020 - Day 1: finding 2 or 3 numbers that add up to 2020

Tags: algorithm, programming-challenge, rust

Next: [Advent of Code 2020 - Day 2: validating passwords](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254260/188857)

## Problem statement

I decided to take a shot at [Advent of Code 2020](https://adventofcode.com/2020) to exercise my Rust knowledge.  Here's the task for Day 1:

> ### Day 1: Report Repair
>
> [...]
>
> Specifically, they need you to **find the two entries that sum to 2020
> and then multiply those two numbers together**.
>
> For example, suppose your expense report contained the following:
>
> ```
> 1721
> 979
> 366
> 299
> 675
> 1456
> ```
>
> In this list, the two entries that sum to 2020 are 1721 and 299.
> Multiplying them together produces 1721 * 299 = 514579, so the correct
> answer is 514579.
>
> [...]
>
> #### Part Two
>
> [...] They offer you a second one if you can **find three numbers in
> your expense report that meet the same criteria**.
>
> Using the above example again, the three entries that sum to 2020 are
> 979, 366, and 675. Multiplying them together produces the answer,
> 241861950.

The full story can be found on the [website](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/1).

## My solution

**src/day_1.rs**

```rust
use {anyhow::Result, std::io::prelude::*};

pub type Number = u64;

pub fn parse_data<R: BufRead>(reader: R) -> Result<Vec<Number>> {
    reader.lines().map(|line| Ok(line?.parse()?)).collect()
}

// Finds a pair of numbers in `data` that add up to `sum`
pub fn find_pair(mut data: Vec<Number>, sum: Number) -> Option<(Number, Number)> {
    data.sort_unstable();

    find_pair_in_sorted(&data, sum)
}

// Finds a triple of numbers in `data` that add up to `sum`.
pub fn find_triple(mut data: Vec<Number>, sum: Number) -> Option<(Number, Number, Number)> {
    data.sort_unstable();

    while let Some(number) = data.pop() {
        let sub_sum = match sum.checked_sub(number) {
            Some(sub_sum) => sub_sum,
            None => continue,
        };

        if let Some((a, b)) = find_pair_in_sorted(&data, sub_sum) {
            return Some((a, b, number));
        }
    }

    None
}

// Finds a pair of numbers in `data` that add up to `sum`
// by binary searching for `sum - n` for each number `n` in `data`.
// `data` must be sorted in ascending order.
pub fn find_pair_in_sorted(mut data: &[Number], sum: Number) -> Option<(Number, Number)> {
    while let Some((&number, new_slice)) = data.split_last() {
        data = new_slice;

        let target = match sum.checked_sub(number) {
            Some(target) => target,
            None => continue,
        };

        if data.binary_search(&target).is_ok() {
            return Some((target, number));
        }
    }

    None
}
```

**src/bin/day_1_1.rs**

```rust
use {
    anyhow::{anyhow, Result},
    aoc_2020::day_1::{self as lib, Number},
    std::{fs::File, io::BufReader},
};

const PATH: &str = "./data/day_1/input";
const SUM: Number = 2020;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(PATH)?);
    let data = lib::parse_data(file)?;

    let (a, b) = lib::find_pair(data, SUM)
        .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("cannot find pair that adds up to {}", SUM))?;
    println!("{} * {} = {}", a, b, a * b);

    Ok(())
}
```

**src/bin/day_1_2.rs**

```rust
use {
    anyhow::{anyhow, Result},
    aoc_2020::day_1::{self as lib, Number},
    std::{fs::File, io::BufReader},
};

const PATH: &str = "./data/day_1/input";
const SUM: Number = 2020;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(PATH)?);
    let data = lib::parse_data(file)?;

    let (a, b, c) = lib::find_triple(data, SUM)
        .ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("cannot find triple that adds up to {}", SUM))?;
    println!("{} * {} * {} = {}", a, b, c, a * b * c);

    Ok(())
}
```

Crates used: [`anyhow` 1.0.37](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.37/anyhow/)

`cargo fmt` and `cargo clippy` have been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is well done and shows familiarity with Rust.

The best I can do is comment on some parts of the code and provide two small, concrete pieces of advice. There is very little room for improvement in the code.

I see your `Vec`s in function parameters are well motivated. The one in `find_triple` is motivated by the need to do `pop`, and the one in `find_pair` just follows the other for consistency between parts of the task.

The decision to introduce `Number` as a type alias is ok, and works and looks fine, but keep in mind that it adds an extra mental hop for the reader.

### Return types

Acting by intuition I'd change the return types to have const-length arrays instead of tuples. This brings attention to the fact that the array/tuple is homogeneous. I would change:

`-> Option<(Number, Number, Number)>` and `return Some((a, b, number));`
to
`-> Option<[Number; 3]>` and `return Some([a, b, number]);`

### Typo?

It's good to be correct and consistent in naming. The function name is `find_triple` - but 'triple' is not a noun, 'triple**t**' is.

Comment: The triple one is fun - MW lists both [triple](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/triple#h2) and [triplet](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/triplet#h1) as nouns.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple#Names_for_tuples_of_specific_lengths) lists triple as the "name" and triplet under alternative names.  I actually thought triplet was only for music - seems they're both acceptable anyway.