# Advent of Code 2020 - Day 2: validating passwords

Tags: programming-challenge, validation, rust

Previous: [Advent of Code 2020 - Day 1: finding 2 or 3 numbers that add up to 2020](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254209/188857)

Next: [Advent of Code 2020 - Day 3: tobogganing down a slope](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254832/188857)

## Problem statement

I decided to take a shot at [Advent of Code 2020](https://adventofcode.com/2020) to exercise my Rust knowledge.  Here's the task for Day 2:

> ### Day 2: Password Philosophy
>
> [...]
>
> To try to debug the problem, they have created a list (your puzzle
> input) of passwords (according to the corrupted database) and the
> corporate policy when that password was set.
>
> For example, suppose you have the following list:
>
> ```
> 1-3 a: abcde
> 1-3 b: cdefg
> 2-9 c: ccccccccc
> ```
>
> Each line gives the password policy and then the password. **The
> password policy indicates the lowest and highest number of times a
> given letter must appear for the password to be valid.** For example,
> `1-3 a` means that the password must contain `a` at least `1` time and
> at most `3` times.
>
> In the above example, `2` passwords are valid. The middle password,
> `cdefg`, is not; it contains no instances of `b`, but needs at least
> `1`. The first and third passwords are valid: they contain one `a` or
> nine `c`, both within the limits of their respective policies.
>
> **How many passwords are valid according to their policies?**
>
> [...]
>
> #### Part Two
>
> While it appears you validated the passwords correctly, they don't
> seem to be what the Official Toboggan Corporate Authentication System
> is expecting.
>
> The shopkeeper suddenly realizes that he just accidentally explained
> the password policy rules from his old job at the sled rental place
> down the street! The Official Toboggan Corporate Policy actually works
> a little differently.
>
> **Each policy actually describes two positions in the password, where `1` means the first character, `2` means the second character, and so
> on.** (Be careful; Toboggan Corporate Policies have no concept of
> "index zero"!) **Exactly one of these positions must contain the given
> letter.** Other occurrences of the letter are irrelevant for the
> purposes of policy enforcement.
>
> Given the same example list from above:
>
> - `1-3 a: abcde` is valid: position `1` contains `a` and position `3` does not.
> - `1-3 b: cdefg` is invalid: neither position `1` nor position `3` contains `b`.
> - `2-9 c: ccccccccc` is invalid: both position `2` and position `9` contain `c`.
>
> **How many passwords are valid according to the new interpretation of the policies?**

The full story can be found on the [website](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/2).

## My solution

**src/day_2.rs**

```rust
use {
    anyhow::{anyhow, Result},
    itertools::{self, Itertools},
    std::str::FromStr,
};

pub const PATH: &str = "./data/day_2/input";

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
pub enum Policy {
    Old,
    New,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
pub struct Entry {
    pub numbers: (usize, usize),
    pub key: char,
    pub password: String,
}

impl Entry {
    pub fn is_valid(&self, policy: Policy) -> bool {
        match policy {
            Policy::Old => {
                let (start, end) = self.numbers;

                let frequency =
                    self.password.chars().filter(|&c| c == self.key).count();

                (start..=end).contains(&frequency)
            }
            Policy::New => {
                let (num_a, num_b) = self.numbers;

                let pos_a = num_a - 1;
                let pos_b = num_b - 1;

                let char_a = match self.password.chars().nth(pos_a) {
                    Some(c) => c,
                    None => return false,
                };
                let char_b = match self.password.chars().nth(pos_b) {
                    Some(c) => c,
                    None => return false,
                };

                (char_a == self.key) ^ (char_b == self.key)
            }
        }
    }
}

impl FromStr for Entry {
    type Err = anyhow::Error;

    fn from_str(text: &str) -> Result<Self> {
        fn parse(text: &str) -> Option<Entry> {
            let (policy, password) = text.split(": ").collect_tuple()?;

            let (range, key) = policy.split(" ").collect_tuple()?;
            let numbers = itertools::process_results(
                range.split("-").map(str::parse),
                |iter| iter.collect_tuple(),
            )
            .ok()??;

            Some(Entry {
                numbers,
                key: key.parse().ok()?,
                password: String::from(password),
            })
        }

        parse(text).ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("invalid entry"))
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn entry_is_valid() {
        let entries = [
            Entry {
                numbers: (1, 3),
                key: 'a',
                password: "abcde".to_owned(),
            },
            Entry {
                numbers: (1, 3),
                key: 'b',
                password: "cdefg".to_owned(),
            },
            Entry {
                numbers: (2, 9),
                key: 'c',
                password: "ccccccccc".to_owned(),
            },
        ];

        assert!(entries[0].is_valid(Policy::Old));
        assert!(!entries[1].is_valid(Policy::Old));
        assert!(entries[2].is_valid(Policy::Old));

        assert!(entries[0].is_valid(Policy::New));
        assert!(!entries[1].is_valid(Policy::New));
        assert!(!entries[2].is_valid(Policy::New));
    }

    #[test]
    fn entry_from_str() -> Result<()> {
        let text = "1-3 a: abcde";

        assert_eq!(
            text.parse::<Entry>()?,
            Entry {
                numbers: (1, 3),
                key: 'a',
                password: "abcde".to_owned(),
            },
        );

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

**src/bin/day_2_1.rs**

```rust
use {
    anyhow::Result,
    aoc_2020::day_2::{self as lib, Entry, Policy},
    std::{
        fs::File,
        io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
    },
};

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(lib::PATH)?);

    let valid_count = itertools::process_results(
        file.lines()
            .map(|line| -> Result<_> { Ok(line?.parse::<Entry>()?) }),
        |entries| entries.filter(|entry| entry.is_valid(Policy::Old)).count(),
    )?;
    println!("{}", valid_count);

    Ok(())
}
```

**src/bin/day_2_2.rs**

```rust
use {
    anyhow::Result,
    aoc_2020::day_2::{self as lib, Entry, Policy},
    std::{
        fs::File,
        io::{prelude::*, BufReader},
    },
};

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(lib::PATH)?);

    let valid_count = itertools::process_results(
        file.lines()
            .map(|line| -> Result<_> { Ok(line?.parse::<Entry>()?) }),
        |entries| entries.filter(|entry| entry.is_valid(Policy::New)).count(),
    )?;
    println!("{}", valid_count);

    Ok(())
}
```

Crates used: [`anyhow` 1.0.37](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.37/anyhow/) [`itertools` 0.10.0](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/)

`cargo fmt` and `cargo clippy` have been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of implementing `FromStr` on `Entry` on your own, you may use crates such as [`parse-display`](https://crates.io/crates/parse-display), [`reformation`](https://crates.io/crates/reformation) or [`recap`](https://crates.io/crates/recap).

Some of the derives on `Policy` and `Entry` seem unnecessary.

Kudos for including tests. It makes the code easier to review.

In tests, when running assertions, I tend to name one of the arguments `expected_foo`, so that the assertion is shorter. Also, this makes it clear which argument is expected and which is the actual result. In your code:

```rust
assert_eq!(
    text.parse::<Entry>()?,
    Entry {
        numbers: (1, 3),
        key: 'a',
        password: "abcde".to_owned(),
    },
);
```

I would change to:

````rust
let expected_entry = Entry {
    numbers: (1, 3),
    key: 'a',
    password: "abcde".to_owned(),
};

assert_eq!(text.parse::<Entry>()?, expected_entry);
```
````

Comment: The `expected_*` one is excellent - it makes the code significantly more readable.  Speaking of unnecessary derives, can you name the particular derives that you deem unnecessary?  I derived the `Eq` series for testing, for example.

Comment: @L.F. Glad it was helpful. After a cursory glance, the only needed ones are for testing: `Debug`, `Eq` + `PartialEq` on `Entry`. Other than that, derives can be removed: you dont hash Entry, you rarely use Policy, and you dont clone Entry. By the way, I would be curious how you'd solve day 19.

Comment: I would generally derive `Clone` as long as it makes sense to clone the type.  I'm curious to know if there are any downsides to this.  As for day 19, I'm thinking of writing a build script or procedural macro to generate a [pest](https://pest.rs/) script.  A little bit cheating, but we'll see :)

Comment: @L.F. I believe there are no downsides to deriving anything, except that a type may no longer support the derive in future versions. So backwards compatibility is the only concern. For clone, the situation is good as you rarely need to remove it.

Obviously your program is a binary, not a library, so you have an easier job here.

Comment: @L.F. Ah, it is the case that with many types and many dervives, the compilation takes longer. It used to be the case that for some derives, their compilation took O(n**2), but it was fixed.