# Advent of Code 2020 - Day 3: tobogganing down a slope

Tags: programming-challenge, parsing, rust

Previous: [Advent of Code 2020 - Day 2: validating passwords](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/254260/188857)

## Problem statement

I decided to take a shot at [Advent of Code 2020](https://adventofcode.com/2020) to exercise my Rust knowledge.  Here's the task for Day 3:

> ### Day 3: Password Philosophy
>
> [...]
>
> Due to the local geology, trees in this area only grow on exact
> integer coordinates in a grid. You make a map (your puzzle input) of
> the open squares (`.`) and trees (`#`) you can see. For example:
>
> ```
> ..##.......
> #...#...#..
> .#....#..#.
> ..#.#...#.#
> .#...##..#.
> ..#.##.....
> .#.#.#....#
> .#........#
> #.##...#...
> #...##....#
> .#..#...#.#
> ```
>
> These aren't the only trees, though; due to something you read about
> once involving arboreal genetics and biome stability, the same pattern
> repeats to the right many times:
>
> ```
> ..##.........##.........##.........##.........##.........##....... --->
> #...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..
> .#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#.
> ..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#
> .#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#.
> ..#.##.......#.##.......#.##.......#.##.......#.##.......#.##..... --->
> .#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#
> .#........#.#........#.#........#.#........#.#........#.#........#
> #.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...
> #...##....##...##....##...##....##...##....##...##....##...##....#
> .#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.# --->
> ```
>
> You start on the open square (`.`) in the top-left corner and need to
> reach the bottom (below the bottom-most row on your map).
>
> The toboggan can only follow a few specific slopes (you opted for a
> cheaper model that prefers rational numbers); start by **counting all
> the trees** you would encounter for the slope **right 3, down 1**:
>
> From your starting position at the top-left, check the position that
> is right 3 and down 1. Then, check the position that is right 3 and
> down 1 from there, and so on until you go past the bottom of the map.
>
> The locations you'd check in the above example are marked here with
> `O` where there was an open square and `X` where there was a tree:
>
> ```
> ..##.........##.........##.........##.........##.........##....... --->
> #..O#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..#...#...#..
> .#....X..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#..#....#..#.
> ..#.#...#O#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#..#.#...#.#
> .#...##..#..X...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#..#...##..#.
> ..#.##.......#.X#.......#.##.......#.##.......#.##.......#.##..... --->
> .#.#.#....#.#.#.#.O..#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#.#.#.#....#
> .#........#.#........X.#........#.#........#.#........#.#........#
> #.##...#...#.##...#...#.X#...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...#.##...#...
> #...##....##...##....##...#X....##...##....##...##....##...##....#
> .#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...X.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.#.#..#...#.# --->
> ```
>
> In this example, traversing the map using this slope would cause you
> to encounter `7` trees.
>
> Starting at the top-left corner of your map and following a slope of
> right 3 and down 1, **how many trees would you encounter?**
>
> [...]
>
> #### Part Two
>
> Time to check the rest of the slopes - you need to minimize the
> probability of a sudden arboreal stop, after all.
>
> Determine the number of trees you would encounter if, for each of the
> following slopes, you start at the top-left corner and traverse the
> map all the way to the bottom:
>
> - Right 1, down 1.
> - Right 3, down 1. (This is the slope you already checked.)
> - Right 5, down 1.
> - Right 7, down 1.
> - Right 1, down 2.
>
> In the above example, these slopes would find `2`, `7`, `3`, `4`, and
> `2` tree(s) respectively; multiplied together, these produce the
> answer `336`.
>
> What do you get if you multiply together the number of trees
> encountered on each of the listed slopes?

The full story can be found on the [website](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/3).

## My solution

**src/day_3.rs**

```rust
use {
    anyhow::{anyhow, bail, ensure, Result},
    itertools::Itertools,
    ndarray::prelude::*,
    std::io::{self, prelude::*},
};

pub const PATH: &str = "./data/day_3/input";

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
pub enum Pixel {
    Empty,
    Tree,
}

impl Pixel {
    pub fn from_char(c: char) -> Result<Self> {
        match c {
            '.' => Ok(Self::Empty),
            '#' => Ok(Self::Tree),
            _ => bail!("invalid pixel"),
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
pub struct Terrain {
    pixels: Array2<Pixel>,
}

impl Terrain {
    pub fn parse_from<R: BufRead>(reader: R) -> Result<Self> {
        TerrainParser::parse(reader.lines())
    }

    pub fn slope_count(&self, delta_x: usize, delta_y: usize) -> usize {
        assert!(delta_y != 0, "delta_y is zero");

        let pixels = &self.pixels;

        (0..pixels.nrows())
            .step_by(delta_y)
            .zip((0..).step_by(delta_x).map(|x| x % pixels.ncols()))
            .filter(|pos| pixels[*pos] == Pixel::Tree)
            .count()
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TerrainParser {
    pixels: Vec<Pixel>,
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
}

impl TerrainParser {
    fn parse<R: BufRead>(mut lines: io::Lines<R>) -> Result<Terrain> {
        let first_line =
            lines.next().ok_or_else(|| anyhow!("empty terrain"))??;
        let mut parser = Self::parse_first_line(&first_line)?;

        for line in lines {
            parser = parser.parse_line(&line?)?;
        }

        let TerrainParser {
            pixels,
            width,
            height,
        } = parser;

        Ok(Terrain {
            pixels: Array2::from_shape_vec([height, width], pixels)?,
        })
    }

    fn parse_first_line(line: &str) -> Result<Self> {
        let pixels: Vec<_> =
            line.chars().map(Pixel::from_char).try_collect()?;

        let width = pixels.len();
        ensure!(width != 0, "zero-width terrain");

        Ok(Self {
            pixels,
            width,
            height: 1,
        })
    }

    fn parse_line(mut self, line: &str) -> Result<Self> {
        let expected_len = self.pixels.len() + self.width;
        self.pixels.reserve_exact(self.width);

        itertools::process_results(
            line.chars().map(Pixel::from_char),
            |pixels| self.pixels.extend(pixels),
        )?;
        ensure!(self.pixels.len() == expected_len, "jagged terrain");

        self.height += 1;
        Ok(self)
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use {super::*, std::io::BufReader};

    #[test]
    fn pixel_from_char() {
        assert_eq!(Pixel::from_char('.').unwrap(), Pixel::Empty);
        assert_eq!(Pixel::from_char('#').unwrap(), Pixel::Tree);
        assert!(Pixel::from_char(' ').is_err());
    }

    #[test]
    fn terrain_parse_from() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        fn parse(input: &str) -> Result<Terrain> {
            Terrain::parse_from(BufReader::new(input.as_bytes()))
        }

        let expected = Array2::from_shape_vec(
            [3, 3],
            [Pixel::Empty, Pixel::Tree]
                .iter()
                .copied()
                .cycle()
                .take(9)
                .collect(),
        )?;
        assert_eq!(parse(".#.\n#.#\n.#.\n")?.pixels, expected);

        assert!(parse("").is_err());
        assert!(parse(". #").is_err());
        assert!(parse(".\n##").is_err());

        Ok(())
    }

    #[test]
    fn terrain_slope_count() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        // .#.
        // #.#
        // .#.
        // #.#
        let pixels = Array2::from_shape_vec(
            [4, 3],
            [Pixel::Empty, Pixel::Tree]
                .iter()
                .copied()
                .cycle()
                .take(12)
                .collect(),
        )?;
        let terrain = Terrain { pixels };

        assert_eq!(terrain.slope_count(1, 1), 1);
        assert_eq!(terrain.slope_count(2, 1), 3);
        assert_eq!(terrain.slope_count(3, 1), 2);
        assert_eq!(terrain.slope_count(1, 2), 1);

        Ok(())
    }
}
```

**src/bin/day_3_1.rs**

```rust
use {
    anyhow::Result,
    aoc_2020::day_3::{self as lib, Terrain},
    std::{fs::File, io::BufReader},
};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(lib::PATH)?);

    let count = Terrain::parse_from(file)?.slope_count(3, 1);
    println!("{}", count);

    Ok(())
}
```

**src/bin/day_3_2.rs**

```rust
use {
    anyhow::Result,
    aoc_2020::day_3::{self as lib, Terrain},
    std::{fs::File, io::BufReader},
};

const SLOPES: &[[usize; 2]] = &[[1, 1], [3, 1], [5, 1], [7, 1], [1, 2]];

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let file = BufReader::new(File::open(lib::PATH)?);
    let terrain = Terrain::parse_from(file)?;

    let product: usize = SLOPES
        .iter()
        .map(|&[delta_x, delta_y]| terrain.slope_count(delta_x, delta_y))
        .product();
    println!("{}", product);

    Ok(())
}
```

Crates used: [`anyhow` 1.0.37](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.37/anyhow/) [`itertools` 0.10.0](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.0/itertools/) [`ndarray` 0.14.0](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/ndarray/)

`cargo fmt` and `cargo clippy` have been applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main files & solution layout

Seems OK. I always order my imports from the most standard to the most specific, so your order is (anyhow, aoc_2020, std) while mine would be (std, anyhow, aoc_2020).

### lib::TerrainParser && lib::Terrain

In future Rust versions, you may do `.flatten()?` instead of the weird-looking `??`. We aren't at that stable point yet.

I would consider implementing `TryFrom<TerrainParser>` for `Terrain` for use in `TerrainParser::parse`. There's an argument against that -- exposing such a method is not needed.

### fn slope_count

I "refactored" the main iteration logic as follows

```rust
let pos_x = (0..pixels.ncols()).cycle().step_by(delta_x);
let pos_y = (0..pixels.nrows()).step_by(delta_y);
pos_y.zip(pos_x)
    .filter(|pos| pixels[*pos] == Pixel::Tree)
    .count()
```

### Testing

Doing the `pixel_from_char` test seems entirely unnecessary. It reflects code 1:1. This is write-once code, but such tests would be a pain in write-often code contexts. Furthermore, you are already running this functionality from other tests. I'd focus on these other tests.

I would change `assert_eq!(parse(".#.\n#.#\n.#.\n")?.pixels, expected);` to

```rust
assert_eq!(
    parse(concat!(
        ".#.\n",
        "#.#\n",
        ".#.\n"
    ))?.pixels,
    expected
);
```

Comment: Helpful review as always.  The import order was chosen by `rustfmt` — this can be overrided with a separate `use std::{ /* ... */ }` though.  The fact that the index order is `(Y, X)` rather than `(X, Y)` also trips me a lot :(  As for testing, I don't think I've been paying enough attention to them, so I'll try to write concise and useful tests in the future.  Thanks!